# How to determine the .Left value of a control?

Tags: vba, ms-access, controls, rectangles

I'm building my first user interface in VBA on Microsoft Access.

I am trying to get the .Left variable to show up in the drop down selection (library?).

The only thing that pops up is LeftPadding, which I'm pretty sure that isn't what I need. Why am I not able to declare the Left position of the rectangles?

[image]

Is there another type of variable that I should be using to declare the position of rectangles?

My follow up issue, if I'm doing that correctly, is about a nested If statement. I'm trying to calculate whether a newly visible rectangle's position + its dimensions exceeds the Left position of an already visible rectangle, and if so, position it elsewhere.

```
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In [Forms]![frmBuilder]
    If Left(ctl.Name, 3) = "box" And Box1.Visible = True Then
        If ctl.Visible = True Then
            NextCaseNum = Int(Right(ctl.Name, (Len(ctl.Name)) - 3) + 1)
            NextCasePosition = (ctl.lef + ctl.Width) + 1440 / 60
            NextCaseName = "box" & NextCaseNum
        Else
            CurCaseLeft = ctl.Left
            CurCaseWidth = ctl.Width
            CurCaseHeight = ctl.Height
            With ctl
                .Top = UprightBottom - HInch
                .Left = NextCasePosition
                .Width = WInch
                .Height = HInch
                .Visible = True
            End With
            If CurCaseLeft + CurCaseWidth > Upright2.Left Then
                With Beam1
                    .Top = (((5.5 + 6) * 60) + Box1.Top) / 1440
                    .Left = Upright1.Left
                    .Height = (5.5 * 60) / 1440
                    .Width = ((4 * 60) / 1440) + Upright2.Left - Upright1.Left
                    .Visible = True
                End With
            End If
```

I think the problem lies with CurCaseLeft and CurCaseWidth, because I don't know how to define them in the function due to the current box's ctl.Left not showing up.

Do I have to separate the nested If statement in to a different function and call that function from the current function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to be more explicit:

```vb
Dim ctl As Control
Dim rct As Rectangle

For Each ctl In [Forms]![frmBuilder]
    If Left(ctl.Name, 3) = "box" And Box1.Visible = True Then
        If ctl.Visible = True Then
            Set rct = ctl
            NextCaseNum = Int(Right(rct.Name, (Len(rct.Name)) - 3) + 1)
            NextCasePosition = (rct.Left + rct.Width) + 1440 / 60
```

Comment: Thanks! That definitely helped